# Networking with ObjectInputStream, Java and Lua clients across TCP sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, lua, stream

I have a Java server that will have two difference types of clients, a Java based console, and a Lua based client that the server will be controlling. I have got the Lua client to talk back and forth with

```
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

I am now trying to get a Java based client to connect and I would like to use

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

The problem I am having is understanding the best way to go about accepting connections, not knowing if it is a Lua or Java client on the other end. Then setting up the proper streams.

Should I just use different ports on the initial connection? I was hoping something more along the lines of sending a string from ObjectOutputStream that BufferedReader could read. Or should I use something lower level to see what is connecting before setting up if it is PrintWriter or ObjectOutputStream.

A link to an in depth tutorial or actual code would work. I am having trouble finding resources beyond the basic setup of one or the other.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If you're not working exclusively with Java clients, you shouldn't be using `ObjectOutputStream`. Use a standard transfer format like XML or JSON, or devise a precise binary record format.

Comment: What would you recommend between XML or JSON? I have about the same experience with both, which is very little.

Comment: JSON is simpler, I'd say, and is designed specifically for representing objects.  If you don't have a specific reason to choose XML, then I'd prefer JSON.  It may be that you don't even need that, however.  It depends on the nature of the messages you need to exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inasmuch as you propose to provide what sounds like two completely different services, it would be natural and appropriate to provide them at different ports.  To implement that, your server would create and manage two separate `ServerSocket`s, listening on different ports.  One would provide one service; the other would provide the other.  You could use either threads or a `Selector` or a combination of those to handle the two server sockets and all the clients.

As a separate matter, I urge you to think carefully before relying on Object streams.  If you can implement your service on top of a simpler and/or more general protocol then you will avoid the multiple joys of Java Serialization, and you will also leave open the door for clients written in other languages.

Comment: Thanks! I already have threads for clients. Are you thinking a thread for each `ServerSocket`? That seems to be the natural thing to do. Ill look into the `Selector`. Thanks for the heads up on Java Serialization, this project is probably simple enough to send with strings or bytes manually.

Comment: Yes, since a given thread can `accept()` on only one `ServerSocket` at a time, you need some way for your program either to monitor which one is ready, or else to service both at the same time.  A `Selector` could do the former in one thread; a separate thread for each `ServerSocket` would be required for the latter.